# How to redirect to another drupal site/alias after file upload

Tags: files

I use the drupal standard to upload files + File Entity. After uploading file eg this is the current URL: https://blabla.com/en/file/abc.pdf. I want to redirect the users to file/add.

Matroschker

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom submit handler onto your form and add a `$form['#redirect']` attribute to the target destination. There are many examples of form redirect questions on this site, and also examples for custom submit handlers for forms.